# Modules decomposition into indecomposables

Tags: modules, abelian-groups

I think it's not true that every module (over arbitrary ring) is the sum of indecomposable modules, but I can't find counterexample and literature about this problem. Can anyone help me?

Also I have similar question: is every abelian group is quasiisomorphic to the direct sum of strongly indecomposable abelian groups? The help in this question (counterexamples, literature) is also needed.

Comment: I gave an example in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409548/directly-indecomposable-rings/409637#409637

Comment: @JackSchmidt:   
It have to be an example, but I can't realize that any group decomposition in this case comes from ring decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such a counterexample in

L.Fuchs, Infinite Abelian Groups, Chap.XIII, Theorem 91.5:

"There is a countable group which has not any non-zero  indecomposable direct summand."

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible to give not such complicated example, maybe not countable?

Comment: @ptashek: I don't know. If I find such an example, I will write to you.