# If in a group $G$ , $(ab)^2=(ba)^2$ for all $a,b \in G$ , then show that $G$ is abelian .

Tags: group-theory

Initially , I have placed $a^{-1}b$ in place of $b$ , and obtained $a^2b= ba^2$   for all $a\in G$. Consequently, i have obtained $ab^2=b^2a$ . Then what to do ?

Comment: Perhaps that you meant $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$.

Comment: It is true under additional hypotheses, compare [$G$ is Abelian if it has no element of order $2$ and $(ab)^2=(ba)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566969/42969) or [Prove that a ring is commutative if $(ab)^2=(ba)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83334/42969)

Comment: The quaternion group does obey the law $ab^2=b^2a$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't. A counterexample is the quaternion group of order $8$.